# docker-compose: when bringing up several containers at once, containers get stuck in init, starting dbus

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dbus, avahi, macvlan

I am using docker-compose to run several instances of image `mikebrady:shairport-sync` on an armbian host, using macvlan networking following [an example configuration here](https://github.com/noelhibbard/shairport-sync-docker). I can bring up each service one at a time and they will work. However, there seems to be a problem if I `docker compose up` the whole group, or more than 3-4 containers at once. The containers will get stuck in the init script. An example log from one container is:

```
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | STARTING - Sun Jan  7 04:01:34 UTC 2024
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service 01-startup successfully started
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service 04-nqptp: starting
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service 02-dbus: starting
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service 04-nqptp successfully started
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | Starting nqptp
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | Starting dbus
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service syslogd-prepare successfully started
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service syslogd-log: starting
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service syslogd-log successfully started
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service syslogd: starting
    shairport-sync_kitchen      | s6-rc: info: service syslogd successfully started
```

If I `docker compose up` only one container at a time, they run successfully and I find the next log messages would have been like:

```
shairport-sync_garage  | s6-rc: info: service 02-dbus successfully started
shairport-sync_garage  | s6-rc: info: service 03-avahi: starting
shairport-sync_garage  | Starting avahi
shairport-sync_garage  | Found user 'avahi' (UID 86) and group 'avahi' (GID 86).
shairport-sync_garage  | Successfully dropped root privileges.
shairport-sync_garage  | avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up.
```

So it seems like these containers are getting stuck bringing up dbus or avahi. How to debug this further? Is is possible to tell docker to stagger the container startups by some delay?

The full docker-compose and other files are [posted here](https://gist.github.com/crowding/41b9852776d61c8de984e7244359337b).

Comment: That sounds like your image is running systemd.  This is a heavy-weight init system that doesn't just manage processes but also tries to manage network setup, physical devices, and several kernel properties.  It's not usually an appropriate thing to run in a single-process Docker container.  Can you change the Dockerfile to directly run the program you need, either without an init system at all or with something minimal like `tini`?

Comment: Actually the image is running s6rc. I believe shairport-sync needs an avahi-daemon running in its container hence the init